# Complexity class of Towers of Hanoi problem

Tags: complexity-theory, towers-of-hanoi

Given a problem

> List all steps to move n disks from rode 1 to rode 2.

I guess you are familiar with Towers of Hanoi rules.
I couldn't find a proper answer for the complexity class of this problem. My first guess would be NP or even NP-hard yet the output is exponential and no matter how hard we try there's no chance to check the answer in polynomial time even on non-deterministic Turing machine. So what's the complexity class?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question asks about printing the _k_ th move given a _k_ and an _n_. This question asks about printing every move given an _n_. The title would benefit from more specificity but the question is different.

Comment: Related, but the precise formulation is different: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/999/755

Comment: The appropriate notion might be [enumeration complexity](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63601/683).